# Алгоритм генерации слов

Tags: алгоритм, php

Нужен алгоритм генерации случайных слов на Английском, не обязательно со смыслом, главное чтоб эти слова легко читались (чередование гласных и согласных)

Comment: Вам наверное к филологам.

Comment: @Fanrin вы забыли дописать несколько слов, я их выделил жирным.

--------------------------------------------------------------

Нужен алгоритм генерации случайных слов на Английском, не обязательно со смыслом, главное чтоб эти слова легко читались (чередование гласных и согласных) **Напишите за меня пожалуйста скрипт!!!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Что вроде такого:

```
$glas = ["a","e","i","y","o","u"];
$soglas = ["b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","x","w","z"];

$wordlen = 5;

for ($i=0; $i <$wordlen/2 ; $i++) { 
  $ng = rand(0, count($glas) - 1);
  $nsg = rand(0, count($soglas) - 1);
  $newWord .= $glas[$ng].$soglas[$nsg];
}

echo $newWord;
```

Comment: Можно еще добавить массив наиболее часто сочетающихся 2ек(3ек..), например ea,ee, th, ... И сочетать с учетом последней буквы двойки, если она согласная, следующую генерить гласную и наоборот....

Comment: Конечно, но, если я правильно понял, тут не обязательно заморачиваться. =)

Comment: Спасибо! Только вот массив не так объявляют в PHP)

Comment: @Fanrin

> Спасибо! Только вот массив не так объявляют в PHP)

Начиная с PHP 5.4 возможно использовать короткий синтаксис определения массивов, который заменяет языковую конструкцию array() на [].

Answer (score 2):

Имеем два массива: гласные и согласные.
В цикле с каждой итерацией получаем сначала из одного рандомный элемент, потом из другого. 
Кол-во итерация задать рандомом. Это самый простой вариант :)

Comment: А можно сразу записать массив со всеми вариантами слогов