# Изменить имя файла при заливке на сервер

Tags: кодировка, php

Здравствуйте. Возникла такая проблема: при загрузке файла, его имя в папке /avatars/ соответствует его изначальному имени на компе пользователя. К примеру, если загружать файл image.jpg, то и в папке /avatars/ он будет image.jpg. Всё бы ничего, но, если имя файла на кириллице, записывается оно крякозябрами. Как можно давать каждому новому файлу рандомное название латиницей/цифрами?

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
            echo '<h3>Ваш профиль был обновлён!</h3> <br>';
            echo 'Вернуться <a href="/example.php">на главную</a> или <a href="/settings.php">назад</a>';
        } else{

            if(empty($_POST) === false) {

                if (isset($_POST['first_name']) && !empty ($_POST['first_name'])){
                    if (ctype_alpha($_POST['first_name']) === false) {
                    $errors[] = 'Please enter your First Name with only letters!';
                    }   
                }
                if (isset($_POST['last_name']) && !empty ($_POST['last_name'])){
                    if (ctype_alpha($_POST['last_name']) === false) {
                    $errors[] = 'Please enter your Last Name with only letters!';
                    }   
                }

                if (isset($_POST['gender']) && !empty($_POST['gender'])) {

                    $allowed_gender = array('не указано', 'Мужской', 'Женский');

                    if (in_array($_POST['gender'], $allowed_gender) === false) {
                        $errors[] = 'Пожалуйста, выбере ваш пол из выпадающего списка'; 
                    }

                }

                if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name'])) {

                    $name           = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
                    $tmp_name       = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
                    $allowed_ext    = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif' );
                    $a              = explode('.', $name);
                    $file_ext       = strtolower(end($a)); unset($a);
                    $file_size      = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];        
                    $path           = "avatars";

                    if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === false) {
                        $errors[] = 'Выбранный вами файл имеет недопустимый формат';    
                    }

                    if ($file_size > 2097152) {
                        $errors[] = 'Максимальный вес файла - 2МБ';
                    }

                } else {
                    $newpath = $user['image_location'];
                }

                if(empty($errors) === true) {

                    if (isset($_FILES['myfile']) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['name']) && $_POST['use_default'] != 'on') {

                        $newpath = $general->file_newpath($path, $name);

                        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newpath);

                    }else if(isset($_POST['use_default']) && $_POST['use_default'] === 'on'){
                        $newpath = 'avatars/default_avatar.png';
                    }

                    $first_name     = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['first_name']));
                    $last_name      = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['last_name']));  
                    $gender         = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['gender']));
                    $bio            = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['bio']));
                    $image_location = htmlspecialchars(trim($newpath));
                    $wall           = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['wall']));

                    $users->update_user($first_name, $last_name, $gender, $bio, $image_location, $wall, $user_id);
                    header('Location: settings.php?success');
                    exit();

                } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
                    echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>';  
                }   
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое с чего надо начать, перед запуском генератора случайных имен, это разобраться с кодировкой, для этого есть функция [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)
пример:

```
 iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $someText);
```

Вырезка из документации:

> Если добавить к out_charset строку
>   //TRANSLIT, включается режим
>   транслитерации. Это значит, что в
>   случае, если символ не может быть
>   представлен в требуемой кодировке, он
>   будет заменен на один или несколько
>   нескольких наиболее близких по
>   внешнему виду символов

Что бы узнать какая кодировка у вашей строки

```
print mb_detect_encoding($res);
```

Поддерживаемые форматы кодировок в PHP: [смотреть](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php)

Или можно сделать транслитерацию, т.е. заменять кирилицу на латиницу напрямик

```
$cyrillicTxt="сделать транслитерацию щЩ ёЖиЩе";

$cyrillicPattern  = array('а','б','в','г','д','e', 'ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у', 
        'ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ь', 'э', 'ы', 'ю','я','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е', 'Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У',
        'Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ь', 'Э', 'Ы', 'Ю','Я' );

$latinPattern = array( 'a','b','v','g','d','e','jo','zh','z','i','y','k','l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u',
        'f' ,'h' ,'ts' ,'ch','sh' ,'sht', '', '`', 'je','ji','yu' ,'ya','A','B','V','G','D','E','Jo','Zh',
        'Z','I','Y','K','L','M','N','O','P','R','S','T','U',
        'F' ,'H' ,'Ts' ,'Ch','Sh','Sht', '', '`', 'Je' ,'Ji' ,'Yu' ,'Ya' );

$cyrillicTxt = str_replace($cyrillicPattern, $latinPattern, $cyrillicTxt);

print 'CYRILLIC: '.$cyrillicTxt;
```

P.S. будете тестировать в браузере, на забудьте проверить какая текущая кодировка у страницы.

Хотите генерацию слов, смотрите в этом вопросе [СМОТРЕТЬ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/171558/php-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2), уже обсуждалось

Или вот, только что идея пришла...

```
$path = '.'; // Ваш путь к дериктории

// Придумать имя для фалов, 
// можно по имени директории или имени пользователя, который аплодит, 
// что бы потом можно было легко ориентироваться
$fileNamePattern = 'HelloWorld';

//Получить количество уже существующих файлов
if ($handle = opendir($path)) { 
    $counter = 0;
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);

    // получить новое имя
    $newFileName  = $fileNamePattern.'-'.$counter;

    print $newFileName;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду тестировать)

Comment: Если это работает для вас, лучшее спасибо - это принятый ответ.